# TabsActivity leaves a vertical gap when adding a view next to tabs using Tabs Activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tabs

[image]

I am trying to put a view horizontally on the right side of the tabs. If i put a view next to tabs, the activity displayed in tabs does not cover the region which is outside tabs thus it leaves a gap for that view. Does anyone know how to fix this.

Temporarily, I am using views instead of Tabs which made my layout very complex.

Comment: you mean you are creating vertical tabs instead of horizontal. Right??

Comment: No,i need three tabs with a spinner. All Horizontally